# SharePoint Online - Is there a 'Global Administrator' Group?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-permissions, office-365-groups, global-administrator

In both "SharePoint Site Settings" and "SharePoint Admin Center", I can assign permissions to 'Global Administrator'.

Is this a built-in Office 365 group? I can't find any documentation on it.

- SharePoint Site Settings

[image]

- SharePoint Admin Center

[image]

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a default SharePoint user, is this an account that someone has added to your tenant?

Comment: @CallumCrowley No, this is a brand new developer tenant that nobody else is using. I noticed this "group" when I had the SharePoint Admin Center automatically create the app catalog in the tenant. This "group" was set as a member of the site collection admins.

Comment: This may be the new name for "Company Administrator" and the change is slowly making it's way across tenants. It makes sense, since using the word "Company" assumes that the owner of the tenant is a commercial business when they may not be. Can't find any documentation for this change, if it is indeed the case.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a built-in group that can't be managed anywhere manually and there's no clear documentation on it right now. However, if one assigned as a Global Admin role, they will be added to the group automatically. I also agree to the comments that it's got 2 names: Global Administrator and Company Administrator.

There is also SharePoint Administrator group for those set as SharePoint Admin role only in the tenant, and also set automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I might be too late to provide my feedback here :)

It's not any built in group but is the custom roles which you can manage it Azure Active Directory.

It does work similarly like Group and you can use it for providing permission in SharePoint as well.

There are lots of roles provided by Microsoft.

**Built-In Roles provided by Microsoft**
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference

Even you can create your custom role in Azure Active Directory.

[image]

I hope that this clarification help to you.